# Bijection function from $(0,1]$ to $[1,\infty)$

Tags: functions

Someone has an idea to Bijection function from $(0,1]$ to $[1,\infty)$ ?

I have thought about $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$

Is this correct ?
Thanks.

Comment: Yes. $1-\ln x$ works too.

Comment: Yes, you're right but you should prove that's indeed a bijection (prove injectivity and surhectivity), can you do it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is correct. Show that $\frac{1}{x}$ is bijective:

- Showing that $\frac{1}{x}$ is injective: Let $x_1$ and $x_2$ be elements of $(0,1]$ such that $\frac{1}{x_1}=\frac{1}{x_2}$. Multiply $x_1 x_2$ on both sides, then we get $x_1=x_2$.
- Showing that $\frac{1}{x}$ is onto: Let $b=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{b}}$ be a element of $[1,\infty)$, then $0<\frac{1}{b}\le \frac{1}{1}=1$. Thus there exists $x^*\in (0,1]$ such that $\frac{1}{x^*}=b$, and so $\frac{1}{x}$ is onto.

Comment: But , $f(5)$ for example is $\frac{1}{5}$.
and $5$ is not in the domain.

Comment: @user3779174 It's the other way around: $\;5=f(1/5)\;$ , and $\;1/5\;$ is in the domain and $\;5\;$ in the codomain

Comment: It was already answered by Joanpemo but just to make it clear: the domain of your function is $(0,1]$ (not $[1 , \infty)$)

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is correct, but a proof is missing:

- $\forall{x_1},{x_2}\in(0,1]:{x_1}\neq{x_2}\implies\frac{1}{x_1}\neq\frac{1}{x_2}$
- $\forall{y}\in[1,\infty),\exists{x}\in(0,1]:y=\frac{1}{x}$ (given $y$, choose $x=\frac{1}{y}$)